# PSPACE≠co-NP?Is the statement true?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, proof-techniques, space-complexity, co-np

Is the statement in question true? how can i prove it formally?
I know that PSPACE=CO-PSPACE and NP ⊆ PSPACE and CO-NP ⊆ CO-PSPACE

Answer (score 4):

If P = PSPACE then since $\text{P} \subseteq \text{coNP} \subseteq \text{PSPACE}$, we can conclude that coNP=PSPACE, and by contrapositive this means that if $\text{coNP} \neq \text{PSPACE}$ then $\text{P} \neq \text{PSPACE}$. Since the question of P vs PSPACE is unsolved, one can conclude that there's no known proof of $\text{coNP} \neq \text{PSPACE}$.